# Select element created dynamically by Firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a website and it shows photos that are in Database of Firebase. I wish that when the heart button was pressed return an alert with selected image's url.

I'm having problems because when I click the button, it returns ALL the urls in the database and not just the URL for the animal that I selected.

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
var read_db = firebase.database().ref('animais/Gato');

read_db.orderByKey().limitToLast(100).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
    var animal = snapshot.key;
    var search_image = firebase.database().ref("animais/Gato/" + animal + "/_img/");

    search_image.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        let $parent = $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'div1'
        });
        let $limits = $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'border'
        });
        let $image = $('<img/>', {
            'src': snapshot.val(),
            'class': 'animal'
        });
        let $bar_like = $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'bar'

        });
        let $icon_like = $('<img/>', {
            'src': 'css/like.png',
            'class': 'icon_like',
            'id': 'btn_like'
        });

        $bar_like.append($icon_like);
        $limits.append($bar_like);
        $limits.append($image);
        $parent.append($limits).appendTo(".put_divs_here");

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn_like").click(function () {
                alert(snapshot.val());
            });
        });
```

[Site screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vVdI.png)

[Website](http://segundo-ong.firebaseapp.com)

Answer (score 0):

I am considering you have created `unique key` for every item.

You just need to get that `unique key` from selected item and fire firebase-query.

```
   var id = 1234   //get selected element key here;
   var read_db = firebase.database().ref('animais/Gato/' + id);
   read_db.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {

       let $parent = $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'div1'
        });
        let $limits = $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'border'
        });
        let $image = $('<img/>', {
            'src': snapshot.val(),
            'class': 'animal'
        });
        let $bar_like = $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'bar'

        });
        let $icon_like = $('<img/>', {
            'src': 'css/like.png',
            'class': 'icon_like',
            'id': 'btn_like'
        });

        $bar_like.append($icon_like);
        $limits.append($bar_like);
        $limits.append($image);
        $parent.append($limits).appendTo(".put_divs_here");

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn_like").click(function () {
                alert(snapshot.val());
            });

});
```

When you use `push()` method in firebase it will automatic generate unique key for your record. use `set()` or `update()` method to create your own custom keys.